# Extracting a specific substring from a column in sql

Tags: mysql, string, substring

i wanted to extract month from a column named **implemented_date** which specifies the date/time as 2018-02-14 15:00:23. I just want 02 from this data and want to view months of all the rows similarly. How can i do it in **mysql**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `DATE_FORMAT` here with the mask `%m`, which would also pad the month number to two digits:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2018-02-14 15:00:23', '%m');
```

This prints `02` as the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Use the MONTH() function like this

```
SELECT MONTH(implemented_date), ..... FROM ....
```